# Regular Expression (in C#) that starts with a string, but matches everything that is after the last occurrence ...

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I'm trying to parse in C# some 'hard-coded' variable initializations (from a custom language) from many files into a db, but I'm having problems:

**Sample Code to Parse  #1  >>>**

```
ArrayName[ArrayIndexVariable].arrayPropertyNameHex            = $A3
```

I'm trying to use the regular expression:

```
string strRegExCriteria = @"^sArrayName\[ArrayIndexVariable\]\.arrayPropertyNameHex.+= ?(.+?)$";
```

Which returns .Success, however:

```
matchRegExCriteria.Groups[1].Value.ToString().Length.ToString();
```

... is equal to **0?**...



**Sample Code to Parse  #2  >>>**

```
ArrayName[ArrayIndexVariable].arrayPropertyNameInt            = 6942
```

I'm trying to use the regular expression:

```
string strRegExCriteria = @"^sArrayName\[ArrayIndexVariable\]\.arrayPropertyNameInt.+?(\d+)$";
```

Which also returns .Success, however:

```
matchRegExCriteria.Groups[1].Value.ToString().Length.ToString();
```

... is equal to **0?**...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried seeing what `Groups[1].Value`, `Groups[1].Value.ToString()`, etc (intermediate values) are? Are they what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you're using the greedy qualifier in your regex.  In your regex (broken up for readability):

```
string strRegExCriteria = @"^sArrayName\[ArrayIndexVariable\]\." +
  @"arrayPropertyNameHex.+= ?(.+?)$";
```

You have `.+` after `arrayPropertyNameHex`, which is "greedily" matching everything to the end of the line, so your capture is never getting hit.  Just change it to the non-greedy match (`+?`), and it should work better:

```
string strRegExCriteria = @"^sArrayName\[ArrayIndexVariable\]\." +
  @"arrayPropertyNameHex.+?= ?(.+?)$";
```

Comment: I discovered at least one problem, I had "whitespace" at the end of the lines...  how would I ignore the whitespace at the end?

Comment: Just stick a `\s*` at the end, before the `$`.  Since the previous match is not greedy, it'll ignore the whitespace.